# Angular2 Material ViewportRuler unit testing error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular2 component, which contains a tab control from `@angular/material`.

I'm trying to test my component (see simplified code below - I get that there's no point in testing a component that's this simple), and am getting the following error:

```
Error: Error in ./MdTabHeader class MdTabHeader - inline template:0:0 caused by: No provider for ViewportRuler!
Error: No provider for ViewportRuler!
```

My assumption was to try and include ViewportRuler (https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/overlay/position/viewport-ruler.ts) as a provider. When I do this (see commented out lines below), karma returns:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at http://localhost:9876/context.html:10
```

Which, from a bit of Googling, suggests that it's serving the .ts file to the browser, rather than the compiled .js. It's possible I'm referencing it from the wrong place.

My question is: *how do I make my tests compile?*

My code is:

my.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: require('./test.component.html')
})
export class TestComponent {

    items: any[];

    constructor() {
        this.items = [{ title: 'test 1', description: 'description 1' }, { title: 'test 2', description: 'description 2' }];
    }
}
```

my.component.html:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab *ngFor="let link of items">
        <template md-tab-label>
            <h4>{{link.title}}</h4>
        </template>
        {{link.description}}
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

my.component.spec.ts:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { ViewportRuler} from '@angular/material/core/overlay/position/viewport-ruler'
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

describe("TestComponent",
    () => {
        let fixture, component;

        beforeEach(() => {

            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [MaterialModule],
                declarations: [TestComponent],
                providers: [
                    //{ provide: ViewportRuler }    
                ]
            });

            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });

        it('true = true', () => {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });        
    });
```

I've tried to include as much info as possible, but I'm new to the whole Angular world, so let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `MaterialModule.forRoot()` in your testing module?

Comment: @stealththeninja that fixed it! Write an answer, and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**2.0.0-beta.3**

`MaterialModule` is deprecated. Developers can either consume individual component modules and their dependencies as needed (e.g. `MdButtonModule`) or create their own custom module.

> **MaterialModule**
>
> - MaterialModule (and MaterialRootModule) have been marked as
>     deprecated.
>
> We've found that, with the current state of tree-shaking
>   in the world, that using an aggregate NgModule like MaterialModule
>   leads to tools not being able to eliminate code for components that
>   aren't used.
>
> In order to ensure that users end up with the smallest code size
>   possible, we're deprecating MaterialModule, to be removed in the a
>   subsequent release.
>
> To replace MaterialModule, users can create their own "Material" modul
>   within their application (e.g., GmailMaterialModule) that imports only
>   the set of components actually used in the application.

https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.3

---

**2.0.0-beta.2**

Material team removed `.forRoot()` making this a non-issue.

> The use of Module forRoot has been deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Instead, just simply import MaterialModule directly:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [
       ...
       MaterialModule,
       ...
   ]
...
});
```

https://github.com/angular/material2/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.2

---

`MaterialModule.forRoot()` sets up the providers, which you'll need in a testing module. This should resolve errors like yours and similar ones like `No provider for MdIconRegistry!`.

Comment: By convention, the forRoot static method both provides and configures services at the same time. From https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root

Comment: MaterialModule is deprecated